# Android manifest for galaxy s3

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have upload the my game that currently support two resolution 1280x800 and 1280x720.
Now i have set in manifest give below

```
<supports-screens
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
         />

       <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />

    </compatible-screens>
```

But still my app is show in galaxy 10" but not in galaxy s3.

I have refer on  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

```
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

Please let me know where i have made the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]  Set this true to in manifest file

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Samsung Galaxy s3 comes under large screen. I guess screensize is 4.8 inches.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations.

Comment: It works for galaxy s3 but same device resolution Vodafone Samsung GT-N7105 not showing device supported list,please let me know you comments

Comment: i suggest you read the content of the first link. I am sure you will be to find the solution